# Print PHP table from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to print/echo a 'users' table from my database 'xxx' in order of who has the biggest amount (number/int) of money but I need the sum between two columns from that table "money" + "bank".

So we have a database name: 'xxx'
Table name: 'users'
Columns: 'money' and 'bank'

I want to make a very simple HTML table with the ranking of the users with their total money.
Also, I want to give positions to the table like 1,2,3,4.

**Example here:**
[image]

What I've done till now is this:

```
<?php 

$servername = "svname.com";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "xxx";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) OR DIE ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
```

```
<?php 
    include 'db.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var rankingCount = 10;
                $("button").click(function () {
                    rankingCount = rankingCount + 10;
                    $("#ranking").load("load-users.php", {
                        rankingNewCount: rankingCount
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="ranking">
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 10";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        echo "<p>" . "<span>Name</span>" . $row['firstname'] . "<span>Money</span>" . $row['money'] . "<span>Bank</span>" . $row['bank'] . "</p>";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "There are no users!";
                }
            ?>
            
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">No</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Money</th>
                    <th scope="col">Bank</th>
                    <th scope="col">Total</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">4</th>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <button>More 10 results here</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';

    $rankingNewCount = $_POST['rankingNewCount'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $rankingNewCount";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<p>" . "<span>Name</span>" . $row['firstname'] . "<span>Money</span>" . $row['money'] . "<span>Bank</span>" . $row['bank'] . "</p>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "There are no users!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: what you exactly want?? sum of `money` &`bank` ?

Comment: I don't know how to make the table dynamic with the PHP and when I press the button to load more 10 rows on the table.. My code works, I get the results from database but I don't know how to make the table with php.

Comment: Is it important to output the row like you retrieve them from the db (in which case the answer would have to improve on the mysql query) else you could sort the rows after retrieving them and before outputting them

Comment: What's your current problem? Are you struggling with the frontend, with PHP, with MySQL?

Comment: well, i get all the information I need from database but I don't know how to make Money + Bank and display the total and then to make the ranking by total amount of money like a rank.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the query to calculate the total:
`SELECT *, (money + bank) AS total FROM users LIMIT 10`

About the index, you could add it in a while-loop when you making the table.

Example:

````
<?php 
    include 'db.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var rankingCount = 10;
                $("button").click(function () {
                    rankingCount = rankingCount + 10;
                    $("#ranking").load("load-users.php", {
                        rankingNewCount: rankingCount
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="ranking">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">No</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Money</th>
                    <th scope="col">Bank</th>
                    <th scope="col">Total</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT *, (money + bank) AS total FROM users LIMIT 10";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        $index = 1;
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo '<tr>
                                <td scope="row">' . $index . '</td>
                                <td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $row['money'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $row['bank'] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $row['total'] . '</td>
                            </tr>';
                            $index++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo '<tr>
                            <td colspan="4">There are no users!</td>
                        </tr>';
                        echo ;
                    }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <button>More 10 results here</button>
    </body>

</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to append results everytime, so the JS code should probably be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var rankingCount = 10;
     $("button").click(function () {
         rankingCount = rankingCount + 10;
         $.ajax({url:'load-users.php',
                 data: {rankingCount: rankingCount},
                 complete: function(resp){
                     $("#ranking").html( $('#ranking').html() + resp );

         }});
  });
```

Php should be as simple as:

```
<?php
$offset = $_POST['rankingCount'] || 0;
$sql = "SELECT name as Name, money as Money, bank as Bank, (money+bank) as total FROM users LIMIT 10, ".$offset;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$buff = '<table width=""><thead><col>'. implode('</col><col>', array_keys($result[0]) ).'</col></thead><tr>';

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $buff .= implode('</tr><tr>', array_map( function($i){ return '<span>'.$i.'</span>'; }, $row ) );
    }
} else {
    $buff .= '<td colspan="4">There are no users!</td>';
}
$buff .= '</tr></table>';
echo $buff;
```

?>